# How high is shower waterproofing treatment supposed to be?

Tags: shower, leak, waterproofing

We noticed a sudden water leak while deep cleaning the master shower with the removable shower head, and quickly found the culprit - the tile "bench" in the shower had a grout joint that has completely separated on the leading edge facing the water, and that allowed water to get behind the tile.

My concern is how easily water showed up in the downstairs dining room. Should there be waterproofing around the whole shower and behind all tiles to prevent that from occurring? This is a relatively new home (2016) and I'm wondering if I should just reseal and move on, or if this is something worth taking up with the builder who has already told me this is "homeowner maintenance." Also, given I know water went all the way through, at least to an HVAC duct, is that cause enough to remove tile and investigate any other damage?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a 2-year-old shower is leaking, something is definitely wrong. Call the builder, and tell him to fix it.

Yes, there's supposed to be waterproofing behind the tiles. The tiles and grout by themselves won't be enough to keep the water out of the wall. I don't know if there are precise rules for how high the waterproofing should go, but I would think at least as high as the shower head. When I built my shower, I went all the way up to the ceiling.

Answer (score -1):

I happen to agree with that the tall when we do here were on from code for new home is red guard rubber 8" up regard all the way to ceiling across top a seal and if possible if need be if you    Tile the ceiling deftly behind the tile and if there's a crack that big that it means there's an issue behind the tile either with 2 by fours or Hardie board or something making the tile move you didn't have to  Check it out  And deftly was the builder's responsibility to make sure that that was not gonna moveIf he had a tile God do it he wasn't watching the guy and it may be the tile guy responsibility but always falls back on the project manager

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's hard to understand what you're talking about when there's no paragraphs or even punctuation; would you edit your answer so it's a bit clearer? thanks.